# Getting entry point scripts path in scripts called by it

Tags: python, python-2.7

Consider you have have a script called `/home/user/pack/test.py`

Within this script we call some helper class which is defined in other file path(using import)
Lets say the Helper file path is:
`/home/user/pack/abc/helper.py`

I wonder if there is a way to get the original launching script path `/home/user/src/test.py` within the Helper script for some usage.

I tried using `__file__` but it gave me `/home/user/pack/abc/helper.py` of course.

**Note: I don't want to pass the launching script path(__file__) as parameter to the Helper class.**

Comment: So you want to know the location of the file to which your class has been imported? Why?

Comment: The Helper class is a setup class, and can be called from many scripts,
I want to do something special if a specified file has launched it

Comment: What do you mean by *"something special"*? That sounds like a bad idea, to be honest - why don't you want an explicit flag controlling the behaviour (which would be easier to implement and make testing much easier)?

Comment: The only way I can think of is to ask the OS for the command used to invoke python iterpreter.

Comment: Something special is to set a path to load a other file from

Comment: The path changes according to the launching file, this should help me take the relevant path to load from

Comment: I can also do this logic in the launching script, but then I do setup out of the helper setup class, not sure its correct either

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I prefer not to add another parameter for relative few times I want to do this, what is your opinion regarding this?

Comment: @Hauzuo Gao: How would you do that?

Comment: *"I prefer not to add another parameter for relative few times I want to do this"* - my opinion, which I thought was clear, is: tough, do it anyway! Adding an extra keyword argument is far less effort than any other implementation is going to be, and I've outlined the other benefits already. It sounds like you have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248731), possibly around poor structure/architecture, but without more information we can't help with that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: okay but don't you think that I should do that logic in the launching script instead? I think that I shouldn't because it's also kind of setup which is being held out of setup class

Comment: As I say, without more information it's impossible to make any sensible suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [**`inspect`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) module from the Standard Library to achieve your goal, this way:

***helper.py***

```
def some_helper():
    print(inspect.stack()[1][1])
```

***test.py***

```
import helper

helper.some_helper()
```

So by executing `test.py` you will get `"path/to/test.py"` as your output inside the `helper.py` function.